# Compute pairwise Pearson correlation with p value for multiple variables using R or python

Tags: python, r, pearson-correlation

I am working with the huge microarray expression data set. I have the expression value of 27000 probes representing 5500 genes across 14 different data points (Variables: D1 to D14). Among these 5500 genes, few genes are represented by multiple probes (i.e., different probes for the same gene). The distribution of probe representation for 5500 genes varies from 1 to 5 (meaning few genes have 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 probes). Now, I want to compute Pairwise Pearson Correlation Coefficient and associated P-value for all the possible combinations of multiple probes of the same gene across 14 different data points (14 variables) and export the result in a 1-Dimensional format. A small portion of my input data table in CSV format is shown below

| ProbeName | Gene | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6 | D7 | D8 | D9 | D10 | D11 | D12 | D13 | D14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A | 9.1 | 6.6 | 8.2 | 9.3 | 9.0 | 8.8 | 9.9 | 7.5 | 10.8 | 9.0 | 8.3 | 11.6 | 9.3 | 10.9 |
| A2 | A | 3.9 | 3.7 | 5.8 | 2.2 | 2.9 | 2.8 | 2.9 | 3.8 | 3.3 | 1.7 | 3.2 | 3.5 | 5.9 | 3.7 |
| A3 | A | 4.6 | 4.8 | 6.8 | 2.8 | 4.3 | 3.5 | 4.2 | 5.3 | 4.5 | 3.3 | 4.0 | 4.3 | 6.9 | 4.7 |
| A4 | A | 3.8 | 3.9 | 5.8 | 3.2 | 4.0 | 2.8 | 3.7 | 4.6 | 3.6 | 2.2 | 3.8 | 4.3 | 5.6 | 3.9 |
| A5 | A | 6.3 | 6.6 | 7.7 | 5.9 | 5.9 | 5.6 | 6.2 | 6.4 | 5.8 | 4.9 | 5.4 | 6.1 | 7.7 | 6.9 |
| B1 | B | 7.5 | 5.5 | 7.1 | 10.2 | 7.2 | 8.6 | 8.3 | 7.1 | 6.1 | 7.0 | 9.2 | 6.4 | 6.4 | 9.4 |
| B2 | B | 4.6 | 4.8 | 5.6 | 4.3 | 4.7 | 4.3 | 4.0 | 5.5 | 4.0 | 3.3 | 3.8 | 5.0 | 5.7 | 4.7 |
| B3 | B | 5.1 | 3.9 | 5.1 | 6.5 | 5.0 | 5.4 | 4.9 | 5.3 | 4.5 | 4.5 | 5.9 | 5.0 | 4.6 | 5.6 |
| B4 | B | 7.6 | 6.1 | 7.5 | 10.9 | 8.0 | 9.2 | 8.5 | 7.1 | 6.3 | 7.4 | 10.0 | 6.9 | 6.9 | 10.2 |
| C1 | C | 3.1 | 6.1 | 3.4 | 2.5 | 3.7 | 3.3 | 2.7 | 5.0 | 2.3 | 3.1 | 2.0 | 3.8 | 2.6 | 3.3 |
| C2 | C | 3.8 | 7.1 | 4.8 | 4.1 | 4.9 | 4.5 | 3.8 | 5.9 | 4.0 | 4.7 | 4.4 | 5.1 | 2.9 | 4.8 |
| C3 | C | 3.8 | 6.1 | 5.5 | 5.4 | 6.3 | 3.9 | 3.4 | 7.8 | 5.3 | 5.7 | 4.8 | 4.0 | 3.5 | 4.3 |
| D1 | D | 12.2 | 11.7 | 11.4 | 10.5 | 11.5 | 11.4 | 10.7 | 12.0 | 11.3 | 10.5 | 9.9 | 11.7 | 10.5 | 10.2 |
| D2 | D | 12.0 | 11.5 | 11.3 | 10.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 10.7 | 11.9 | 11.2 | 10.6 | 9.9 | 11.7 | 10.3 | 10.2 |
| E1 | E | 2.4 | 3.3 | 7.5 | 3.4 | 5.8 | 3.6 | 1.2 | 3.5 | 0.9 | 2.2 | 3.1 | 4.7 | 7.5 | 4.0 |

The ProbeName column represents the name of the probes from A1 to E1, the Gene column represents the name of the genes from A to E, and Columns D1 to D14 (variables) represent the expression values in different data points. Rows represent the expression value of a probe representing a particular gene in 14 different data points (i.e., how much a particular gene is activated in 14 different data points with the respective probes). A1, A2, A3, A4 & A5 represent multiple probes for the same gene A, and likewise for the other genes B, C, D, and E. In this Table, I want to compute the possible pairwise Pearson correlation of multiple probes for the same gene across 14 data points (D1 to D14). For Example, the possible probe combinations for gene C to compute Pearson correlation across 14 data points are

1. C1 (D1:3.1, D2:6.1, D3:3.4, D4:2.5, D5:3.7, D6:3.3, D7:2.7, D8:5.0,
   D9:2.3, D10:3.1, D11:2.0, D12:3.8, D13:2.6, D14:3.3) Vs C2 (D1:3.8,
   D2:7.1, D3:4.8, D4:4.1, D5:4.9, D6:4.5, D7:3.8, D8:5.9, D9:4.0,
   D10:4.7, D11:4.4, D12:5.1, D13:2.9, D14:4.8),
2. C1 (D1:3.1, D2:6.1, D3:3.4, D4:2.5, D5:3.7, D6:3.3, D7:2.7, D8:5.0,
   D9:2.3, D10:3.1, D11:2.0, D12:3.8, D13:2.6, D14:3.3) Vs C3 (D1:3.8,
   D2:6.1, D3:5.5, D4:5.4, D5:6.3, D6:3.9, D7:3.4, D8:7.8, D9:5.3,
   D10:5.7, D11:4.8, D12:4.0, D13:3.5, D14:4.3),
3. C2 (D1:3.8, D2:7.1, D3:4.8, D4:4.1, D5:4.9, D6:4.5, D7:3.8, D8:5.9,
   D9:4.0, D10:4.7, D11:4.4, D12:5.1, D13:2.9, D14:4.8) Vs C3 (D1:3.8,
   D2:6.1, D3:5.5, D4:5.4, D5:6.3, D6:3.9, D7:3.4, D8:7.8, D9:5.3,
   D10:5.7, D11:4.8, D12:4.0, D13:3.5, D14:4.3)

After generating the correlation matrix of the possible pairwise combinations of multiple probes for the same gene across 14 data points, I want to flatten only the upper or lower triangular correlation matrix and generate the output in CSV format as mentioned below.

| ProbeName_1 | ProbeName_2 | Gene | PearonCorrelationValue | Pvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | A | -0.129 | 0.661 |
| A1 | A3 | A | -0.176 | 0.547 |
| A1 | A4 | A | -0.106 | 0.718 |
| A1 | A5 | A | -0.084 | 0.776 |
| A2 | A3 | A | 0.963 | 0.000 |
| A2 | A4 | A | 0.932 | 0.000 |
| A2 | A5 | A | 0.914 | 0.000 |
| A3 | A4 | A | 0.922 | 0.000 |
| A3 | A5 | A | 0.883 | 0.000 |
| A4 | A5 | A | 0.882 | 0.000 |
| B1 | B2 | B | -0.328 | 0.253 |
| B1 | B3 | B | 0.900 | 0.000 |
| B1 | B4 | B | 0.987 | 0.000 |
| B2 | B3 | B | -0.084 | 0.774 |
| B2 | B4 | B | -0.322 | 0.261 |
| B3 | B4 | B | 0.882 | 0.000 |
| C1 | C2 | C | 0.888 | 0.000 |
| C1 | C3 | C | 0.542 | 0.045 |
| C2 | C3 | C | 0.658 | 0.011 |
| D1 | D2 | D | 0.993 | 0.000 |

I do not know how to deal with this complex data either with R or Python. I humbly request the experts to help me with this problem.

Note:  I do not want the correlation value of identical probe combinations i.e., A1 Vs A1 or A2 Vs A2 or A3 Vs A3 or A4 Vs A4 or A5 Vs A5. I also do not want to perform a pairwise combination of a probe of one gene with the probe of another different gene. i.e., A1 Vs B1, B2, B3, B4 or A1 Vs C1, C2, C3 or A1 Vs D1, D2, and or A1 Vs E1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What form does your input data take? Do you get it from a database, CSV file, some other file format? Also, can you put some expected values in your output sample? In that way, if someone creates a solution they can check that the values are as expected. Are there always exactly 3 probes for the same gene?

Comment: Hi, My input data is in CSV format. There are not always 3 probes per gene. The probe representation of genes varies from 1 to 5. As asked, I have included the expected output values for reference. In fact, I have edited my question in detail. Please kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your input data is in a tab-delimited CSV file and that the gene samples are all consecutive. Given that then this should suffice.

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr as P
import pandas as pd


def combos(n, s):
    r = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            r.append((i + s, j + s))
    return r


def process(df, s, e, ad):
    if (e - s) > 0:
        _, c = df.shape
        for r1, r2 in combos(e - s + 1, s):
            r, p = P(df.iloc[r1, 2: c], df.iloc[r2, 2: c])
            ad.append([df.iloc[r1, 0], df.iloc[r2, 0],
                       df.iloc[r1, 1], r, p])


def main(csvFile):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, sep='\t')
    r, _ = df.shape
    gene = df.iloc[0, 1]
    startRow = 0
    endRow = 0
    allData = []
    for _r in range(1, r):
        _g = df.iloc[_r, 1]
        if _g == gene:
            endRow = _r
        else:
            process(df, startRow, endRow, allData)
            gene = _g
            startRow = _r
    process(df, startRow, r - 1, allData)

    newDF = pd.DataFrame(data=allData, columns=[
                         'ProbeName_1', 'ProbeName_2', 'Gene', 'Pearson', 'Pvalue'])
    with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:0.4f}'.format):
        print(newDF)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('genes.csv')
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. There are not always 3 probes per gene. The probe representation of genes varies from 1 to 5. I have edited my question. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Hi DarkKnight, Thanks for your response. I am a beginner in python and finding difficult to write the output in CSV format. Could you please help me in this regard.

Comment: You'll find the pandas documentation very helpful in this respect

Comment: Thanks,  Figured how to write the output. Once again thank you so much for helping to solve my Issue.